# Cant render object on canvas after loading from json

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, fabricjs

I may have many different shape objects on canvas and  i my store and get them back on canvas
from db.

```
function getJsonF(){ ////////////////////////////////////                              JSgetjson
   var fromSelectProject=document.getElementById("selectProject").value; 
$.ajax({
  method:"POST",
  url: '/wp-content/themes/mypage/PgetJson.php',
  data:  {
    "getCanvas":1,
    "hProject":fromSelectProject
  },
  datatype: "text",
  success: function(strdate){

     canvas.loadFromJSON( strdate);
     canvas.renderAll();

     }
 });
}
```

but once i add image on canvas

```
 document.getElementById('imgLoader').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (f) {
        var data = f.target.result;     
        fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
        var oImg = img.set({id: "oImgID",left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:canvas.width, height:canvas.height,}).scale(1); 
        canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
        oImg.set('selectable', false);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
        });
      };
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
```

then i must use next to see objects on canvas again.

```
function renderAllF(){
canvas.renderAll();
}
document.getElementById("renderAllID").onclick= renderAllF;
```

What is happening here with rendering of objects?
What must I do to get objects without to press on renderAllID button?

Comment: Are you using fabricjs? If you are you should add that to your tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [**`loadFromJSON()`**](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromJSON) method is asynchronous, you would have to render the canvas within its callback function.

So, instead of doing ...

```
...
canvas.loadFromJSON(strdate);
canvas.renderAll();
...
```

You should do something like ...

```
...
canvas.loadFromJSON(strdate, function() {
   canvas.renderAll();
});
...
```

or ...

```
...
canvas.loadFromJSON(strdate, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
...
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I was working on this problem  for 10 hours . I should ask before.